# 2 Persons toss a fair cube. $X$ is the toss times when $A$ gets $1$, and $Y$ is the toss times when $B$ gets $1$. What is the probability $P(X > Y)$?

Tags: probability

Can you give me some hints and help to solve this question? I've forgotten a bit the technique.

> Danny and Alex making a series of tossing a fair cube.
>
> Let $X$ be random variable which its value is the times Danny tossed the cube until got $1$,
>
> And Let $Y$ be random variable which its value is the times Alex tossed the cube until got $1$.
>
> Calculate $P(X > Y)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do they take turns?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes

Comment: @AndréNicolas When one gets $1$ the game is over

Answer (score 1):

We show how to solve the problem on the assumption they alternate, that A goes first, and that the game is over when a $1$ is tossed. (That was mentioned in comments, but it is not my interpretation of the wording.)

It is clear that with probability $1$ the game terminates. Let $a$ be the probability that A wins. We condition on the result of the first toss.

If the first toss is a $1$, then A has won. The conditional probability that she wins given that she did not toss a $1$ is $1-a$, for the roles of A and B are now reversed. It follows that
$$a=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}(1-a).$$
Now we can find $a$.

**Another way:** The probability A wins on the first toss is $1/6$. The probability she wins on the third toss is $(5/6)^2(1/6)$, for A must toss a non-$1$, then B must toss a non-$1$, then A must toss a $1$. Calculate in the same way the probability A wins on the fifth toss, and so on, and sum the resulting series.

**Remark:** From the wording, it looks as if A and B keep separate counts.  So my interpretation of the problem is different from OP's interpretation. We solve the problem under this interpretation.

By symmetry, we have $\Pr(X\gt Y)=\Pr(Y\gt X)$. It follows that
$$\Pr(X\gt Y)=\frac{1-\Pr(X=Y)}{2}.$$
Now we calculate $\Pr(X=Y)$. The probability that $X=Y=1$ is $(1/6)^2$. The probability that $X=Y=2$ is $((5/6)(1/6))^2$. Continue.

Comment: I got final of $\frac{5}{11}$. But I would never answer this in your way. can you please explain me that logic behind?

Comment: With your interpretation, if A goes first and they alternate and the game is over as soon as there is a $1$, the probability A wins is $\frac{6}{11}$. I don't see how you got $\frac{5}{11}$. For your interpretation of the problem, I gave two approaches. Maybe you would have chosen the second one, but I wanted to show that conditioning on the first toss is a powerful technique. Or are you referring to my interpretation in the remark? Then the sum is $(1/6)^2(1+(5/6)^2+(5/6)^4+\cdots)$, and then the sum of the geometric series is $1/11$, giving $5/11$ for $\Pr(X\gt Y)$. (More)

Comment: As to the logic, I imagine you can see the symmetry. So $2\Pr(X\gt Y)+\Pr(X=Y)=1$ (probabilities add up to $1$) which gives the displayed formula in the remark. The reason I made the interpretation is that $X$ is the number of times Danny tossed, and $Y$ the number of times Alex tossed. But of course your interpretation is reasonable, game over when we get a $1$, in which case the first solutions are right.

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading it again and I'll try to get the point.